# Creating layout variation with both the sw-600 and landscape qualifiers in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-orientation

I have already created a Landscape variation and a Tablet variation of my layout. However, I also want to create a variation that is just for tablets in landscape mode. I had thought this would be possible by clicking the orientation button in the design toolbar, then selecting 'Create Other..." to select multiple qualifiers. However Android Studio will not allow me to create a variant with both the sw-600 and land qualifiers. It gives me an error message saying the layout resource already exists. But looking in my project directory, I don't see it.

I'm still pretty new to android so I apologize if the answer to this should be obvious. Thanks for any help you can give!

[Screenshot showing my Project directory, new resource dialog, and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWTIy.jpg)

Comment: try to use `res\layout-w600dp-land` by manually creating the directory and adding the layout variation inside

Comment: @Zain thank you, can you tell  me more bout how to go about doing that? Would I just create a directory called res\layout-sw600dp-land and put the layout file inside it? If so, would I still need to give the layout file any qualifiers?

Comment: The layout file itself does not need any qualifiers.  Android will know your intent to use this with a smallest width of 600dp in landscape by virtue of the parent folder name.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `layout-sw600dp-land`.  See the [Add orientation qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#TaskUseOriQuali) Android developer documentation for more information.

To do this, manually create a new folder under your res directory named `layout-sw600dp-land` from the command line and place your new layout xml file there.